# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not working in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, app-id

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        registerForPushNotifications()
        return true
    }
    func registerForPushNotifications() {
 UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
          [weak self] granted, error in

          print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
          guard granted else { return }
            self!.getNotificationSettings()
      }
      }
    func getNotificationSettings() {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

      }
    }
    func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {
      let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
      let token = tokenParts.joined()
      print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
      print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }
```

this is the code where I have implemented remote notifications registration methods.
this is what I have done so far:

- I have configuring push notification by Targets -> Signing&Capabilities and correctly entered team and build indentifier.
- Add the push notification capability by tapping + at the top left.
- I have enabled the push notification by going into the iPhone setting.
- wifi is on from the iPhone.

This is what I have tried so far to resolve this:

- Restart the phone, disable and then enable wifi
- Tried to change bundle identifier
- Remove the push notification capability and added it again but nothing helped so far.

App asks for the permission for push notification and even after granting the permission, last two methods are not being called. what have I done wrong? I have seen other similar question and tried everything but still could not figure out what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` inside `getNotificationSettings` method, call it directly inside "`registerForPushNotifications`" after verifying requestAuthorization response "`granted`" is true.

You need not validate `"settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized"` before calling "`registerForRemoteNotifications`" method.

```
 func registerForPushNotifications() {
     UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
          [weak self] granted, error in

          print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
          guard granted else { return }
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
             UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
          }
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. my code is working fine now but I don't know what was the problem.

Comment: It is not supposed to check for authorisation status at that point and call registerForRemoteNotification. It should be called once the user gives allow permission by checking grant value. Pls accept the answer if it really solves ur case.

Comment: I am saying that the code I posted above in the question is working now without doing any changes. that's what is happening in my code what you are suggesting. first it checks for user permission, if user grant the permission than it calls getNotificationSettings where remote notification registration is happening.

Comment: My bad....anyways, nice to hear that something is getting resolved..meanwhile I will explore where I have gone wrong..thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate your permission logic from the remote notifications.

The call of `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` will always lead to `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` or `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`.

I would recommend

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

  // If you want to ask for push permissions immediately on first start (I wouldnt recommend)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { ... }
  return true
}
```

This means you will receive the push token. You can use this token to already send pushes to the device.
However, notifications will only be displayed once the user grants `.alert` permission.

Comment: the problem is I am not receiving the token. token never gets printed

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I'm very sure it will cause the. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`to fire.

Comment: yes I tried it but unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. I am not getting any error but these two methods are not being called either

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and I fixed it with putting registerForRemoteNotifications logic after Firebase.configuration() in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method.